# Converting a Table to a List of Values

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I’m using the function `binning` from the `sm` package to take the plotted x,y coordinates and place them into discrete bins.  This creates a frequency table where the number of bins are determined by user input of SampleSize.

```
    num_bins <- max(x_max,y_max)/SampleSize
    bin_breaks <- matrix(c(bins,bins), num_bins+1,2)
    frequency <- binning(combo_points,breaks=bin_breaks,nbins=num_bins)$table.freq
```

Output of my 'frequency' table is in the format...

```
       x1  x2  x3  x4  x5...
    y1  0   5
    y2  0
    y3  0
    y4
    y5
    .
    .
    .
```

But I need to convert it to a list format for all values of x and y...

```
    x  y  count
    1  1  0
    1  2  0
    1  3  0
    2  1  5
    .  .  .
    .  .  .
```

I want to convert this table into a data.frame list of x,y,count where x and y are now really just the x,y coordinate of the bin itself.  I'm currently doing this by setting up a data.frame to list the bin coordinates (freq_points$x and freq_points$y), then running a for loop that searches for the data in the table that matches the values of for each row of my freq_points data.frame to create a new vector (z) for which each iteration of the for loop appends to... but with over 3.4-million bins, this process takes hours.

```
    for (i in 1:length(frequency)){
    z<-append(z,frequency[freq_points$y[i],freq_points$x[i]])}
```

Can someone recommend a more elegant solution?  Is there a more direct way to convert from a table to a list?  I'm very new in R, perhaps I'm using the terms 'table' and 'list' incorrectly here.  I hope the formats given above help to clarify my question.

output from 'dput(frequency)'
[image: output from 'dput(frequency)']

I had some trouble when applying the answer below to my data which doesn't have x1,x2,y1,y2 as actual row and column header names.  I was using those to try to get my point across, but seemed to have caused more confusion.  For this, I apologize.  Going with the small matrix provided by @neerajt... I do not understand the output and why count.1, count.2, and count.3 are given.  None of those 'count' columns can be used with the x,y coordinates.  Can you please shed some light on this?

```
    freq <- matrix(c(0,0,1,5,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow=4,ncol=3)
    freq
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    0    0    1
    [2,]    0    1    1
    [3,]    1    1    1
    [4,]    5    0    0

    counts <- unlist(freq)
    xname <- rep(c(1:ncol(freq)),nrow(freq))
    yname <- rep(c(1:nrow(freq)),ncol(freq))
    z <- data.frame(x=xname, y=yname, count=counts, row.names=NULL)
    z
       x y count.1 count.2 count.3
    1  1 1       0       0       1
    2  2 2       0       1       1
    3  3 3       1       1       1
    4  1 4       5       0       0
    5  2 1       0       0       1
    6  3 2       0       1       1
    7  1 3       1       1       1
    8  2 4       5       0       0
    9  3 1       0       0       1
    10 1 2       0       1       1
    11 2 3       1       1       1
    12 3 4       5       0       0
```

Comment: can you `dput` frequency please

Comment: have you tried `as.data.frame(frequency)`?

Comment: as.data.frame didn't change the structure of the data from a table into a 3-column (x,y,z) data.frame.

Comment: Is there a way that I can post my 'frequency' output table?  I can't find a way to insert it to my original question.  I'm both new with R and new to SO.  They're both great!!!

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output from `dput(frequency[1:5, 1:5])` please, as Michaels suggestion i would of thought should of worked

Comment: The output from dput() shown is only a fraction of the total output.  Either way, I don't understand what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output frequency table from the 'binning' operation produced a table that is NOT a data.frame, so using the unlist() function will not work properly until applying it as.data.frame(frequency).

```
xname <- rep(1:ncol(frequency),times=1,each=nrow(frequency))
yname <- rep(1:nrow(frequency),times=ncol(frequency),each=1)
z <- unlist(as.data.frame(frequency))
df <- data.frame(x=xname, y=yname, z=count)
```

Also, please note that the replicate function as proposed by @neerajt needed to include the 'each' function in order to create the correct x,y coordinate lists, such that it would correspond to the way 'unlist()' prepared the count data as a vector.

unlist() provided the key to turning hours of computation time into mere seconds.  Thank you all for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try. If you have a `freq` table that looks like this:

```
freq = data.frame(x1=c(0,0,1,5), x2=c(0,1,1,0), x3=c(1,1,1,0))
row.names(freq) <- c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4")
```

```
   x1 x2 x3
y1  0  0  1
y2  0  1  1
y3  1  1  1
y4  5  0  0
```

Then

```
counts = unlist(freq)

xname = rep(names(freq), nrow(freq))

yname = rep(row.names(freq), length(freq))

z = data.frame(x = xname, y = yname, count = counts, row.names=NULL)
```

`z` will return

```
    x  y count
1  x1 y1     0
2  x2 y2     0
3  x3 y3     1
4  x1 y4     5
5  x2 y1     0
6  x3 y2     1
7  x1 y3     1
8  x2 y4     0
9  x3 y1     1
10 x1 y2     1
11 x2 y3     1
12 x3 y4     0
```

Hope that gets you close. The main takeaway is the `unlist()` operation.

When it comes down to terminology, both are tables, or more specifically `data.frames` in R. The difference is your original table (`frequency`) is in **wide** format, and the table you're going for (`z`) is **long** format. [This article](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) illustrates the idea nicely.